# Copying image from page results in black image

Tags: winforms, image, copy, save, webbrowser-control

I have a program that copies images from a webpage and saves them locally. On certain webpages  the saved image is a completely black screen. First I thought it was a problem in the code that didn't take the good picture. So I started investigating. I went manually to those pages and tried to copy the image(right click, copy image) and it still returned a black image. Can someone tell me how can I bypass this from code? Here is the current code, which works fine for most of the pictures

```
IHTMLDocument2 doc = (IHTMLDocument2)webBrowser1.Document.DomDocument;
        IHTMLControlRange imgRange = (IHTMLControlRange)((HTMLBody)doc.body).createControlRange();

        foreach (IHTMLImgElement img in doc.images)
        {
            if (img.alt != "my image alt")
                continue;
            imgRange.add((IHTMLControlElement)img);

            imgRange.execCommand("Copy", false, null);

            using (Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap)Clipboard.GetDataObject().GetData(DataFormats.Bitmap))
            {
                if (bmp != null)
                {
                    bmp.Save("testimg.jpg");
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Which pages? Is Flash involved?

Comment: @SLaks nope no flash involved. http://bestsoftware2download.com/submit.php....the captcha image from this webpage for example....try copy paste directly from browser

Comment: That image has a transparent background.

Comment: @Slaks and what do you suggest? I do no understand how this affects the image. Because accessing the source is obviously out of the question(it returns a different image). And this worked well on a lot of websites. Can i somehow work with the image and transform it?

Answer (score 1):

That image has a transparent background.
Therefore, every pixel in the image is black, except that most of them are fully transparent.

Since `.jpg` files do not support transparency, saving it as a `.jpg` results in a black image.

If you save it as a `.png` file (which does support transparency), it should work.

Comment: Tried bmp.Save(path, ImageFormat.Png), image is still black. Also tried every image format from the ImageFormat class, without success. I also looked into the ImageCodecInfo class but did not manage to make it work

Comment: @CristiM: Then it's probably a problem with the copy operation; I've had trouble getting IE to copy transparency.

Comment: You know any way I could modify the webBrowser control from a winform in order to do this?? Btw, I tried copying the image from chrome into photoshop, without results. Or any other suggestions that I could use?