# how to get captcha image if src use java function?

Tags: vb.net, captcha

How can I scrape captcha from [this website](http://www.irctc.co.in)
captchaImage.

I tried MSHTML but this website uses java script function to display retrieve captcha in it's src. Please try and answer me how can I achieve this.

```
Imports MahApps.Metro.Controls
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Windows.Forms


Class MainWindow
    Inherits MetroWindow

    Private Sub MetroWindow_Loaded(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
        wb.Navigate("https://www.irctc.co.in/eticketing/loginHome.jsf")
        AddHandler wb.LoadCompleted, AddressOf wb_Loaded
    End Sub
    Private Sub btngo_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles btngo.Click
        Dim htmldoc As MSHTML.IHTMLDocument2 = wb.Document
        Dim usrtxtdoc As MSHTML.IHTMLElement = htmldoc.all.item("j_username", 0)
        Dim usrpwddoc As MSHTML.IHTMLElement = htmldoc.all.item("j_password", 0)
        Dim captchadoc As MSHTML.IHTMLElement = htmldoc.all.item("j_captcha", 0)
        usrtxtdoc.innerText = txtusrname.Text
        usrpwddoc.innerText = txtpwd.Text
        captchadoc.innerText = txtcaptcha.Text
    End Sub

    Private Sub wb_Loaded(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs)
        MsgBox("Loaded")
        Dim htmldoc As MSHTML.IHTMLDocument2 = wb.Document
        Dim htmldoc2 As MSHTML.HTMLDocument = wb.Document
        Dim captchaimg As MSHTML.HTMLImg = htmldoc.all.item("cimage", 0)
        Dim bitmap As New BitmapImage
        bitmap.BeginInit()
        bitmap.UriSource = New Uri(wb.FindResource("captchaImage"))
        bitmap.EndInit()
        imgcaptcha.Source = bitmap
    End Sub

    Private Sub wb_Navigated(sender As Object, e As NavigationEventArgs) Handles wb.Navigated
        lblwbstatus.Content = "Load Completed"
    End Sub

    Private Sub wb_Navigating(sender As Object, e As NavigatingCancelEventArgs) Handles wb.Navigating
        lblwbstatus.Content = "Navigating Please wait"
    End Sub

    Private Sub lblwbstatus_MouseDoubleClick(sender As Object, e As MouseButtonEventArgs) Handles lblwbstatus.MouseDoubleClick
        wb.Refresh()
    End Sub
End Class
```

you can download source from [this link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3z2ku0nhW4kc0x2WUZtc19CSFk/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: i am new stackoverflow so please don't rate my question down i appreciate that you edited my question buy please don't rate it down i really need solution

Comment: https://www.irctc.co.in/eticketing/captchaImage

Comment: No jhonkiller, i am saying that when this CAPTCHA got loaded in webbrowser control it called java function to get image but when you again call this CAPTCHA function using SRC as you told in you comment it called CAPTCHA java function separately and genrate new captch image. i need a some way so i can retrieve CAPTCHA image that loaded in the DOM document

Comment: thats because the CAPTCHA is stored in a session variable. when you request the image URL,the session gets refreshed. let me think if there is a way. what is your final goal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally you would do this:

```
    Dim htmldoc As mshtml.IHTMLDocument2 = wb.Document.DomDocument
    Dim captchaimg As mshtml.HTMLImg = htmldoc.all.item("cimage", 0)
    Dim imgRange As IHTMLControlRange = htmldoc.body.createControlRange()
    For Each img As IHTMLImgElement In htmldoc.images
        If img.nameProp = "captchaImage" Then
            imgRange.add(img)
            imgRange.execCommand("Copy", False, Nothing)
            Using bmp As Bitmap = Clipboard.GetDataObject().GetData(DataFormats.Bitmap)
                bmp.Save("c:\test.bmp")
            End Using
        End If
    Next
```

However the image has an alpha channel that doesn't get copied to clipboard because of internet explorer issues (as you can read here [Copying image from page results in black image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12881758/copying-image-from-page-results-in-black-image)).

Other ways are to check on internet explorer cache, but that image won't be cached because of HTTP headers, so you are out of luck.

Comment: Thank you bro i'll try this and respond to you answer

Comment: is there some other library which can do this? Like HTML agility pack of some other?

Comment: what's your final goal? provide a login facility?

Comment: Yes i want to provide login and ticket booking facality without showing webbrowser contol i want to ask you something. Is there any way to get screenshot of webbrowser control so i can capture screenshot of captch i appreciate you help

Answer (score 0):

the code above work very good with consideration -to the:
1-  Item type- as in your webpage target example ("IMG").
 
2- the image proper name example: CaptchaImg.jpg to be written as CaptchaImg.jpg
3- add reference to (mshtml) and Imports mshtml into your project
4- right-Click reference on your project --> click add reference -->
-->Browse button click -choose or navigate to --->
C:\Windows\assembly\GAC\Microsoft.mshtml\7.0.3300.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.mshtml.dll 
----> ok button click --- this will add Microsoft.mshtml.dll to your reference 
finallt import to your project as (Imports mshtml).
5- change the directory bmp.Save("c:\test.bmp")---> to for example bmp.Save("c:\test\test.bmp")
for security and administration right privileged.